# How can I modify my data in a CSV file and change the rows and columns?

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a CSV file and the format of my data is as follows:

```
Countries  variable  1995   1996  1997  1998   1999
  USA        GDP      10     11    12    12     13 
  USA        Inf      100    120   130   120    110
  USA        Trade    200    220   210   235    250
  GER        GDP      8      9     9.5   10     10.5
  GER        Inf      100    105   107   109    111 
  GER        Trade    150    156   149   165    167
```

I intend to modify my data and change it to something like:

```
  Countries  Years    GDP    Inf   Trade
     USA      1995     10    100    200
     USA      1996     11    120    220
     USA      1997     12    130    210
     USA      1998     12    120    235
     USA      1999     13    110    250
     GER      1995     8     100    150
     GER      1996     9     105    156
     GER      1997     9.5   107    149
     GER      1998     10    109    165
     GER      1999     10.5  111    167
```

I have no idea about the way I can do this in Python. I have imported my data in pandas but the only thing can be done on data is transposing the column and rows which is not the one I am looking for. Also by using `csv.writerow` I was not able to modify my data.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a Ordereddict to group the data:

```
import csv
from collections import OrderedDict,defaultdict
from itertools import islice
with open("out.csv") as f:
    od = OrderedDict()
    r = csv.reader(f, delimiter=" ")
    header = next(r)
    years = header[2:]
    zipped = zip(*r)
    countries = OrderedDict.fromkeys(zipped[0]).keys() # next(zipped) python3
    it = iter(countries)
    for  row in zip(*zipped[1:]): #  for  row in zip(*zipped) python3
        if row[0] == "GDP":
            key = next(it)
            od.setdefault(key, defaultdict(list))
            od[key]["Years"] = years
            od[key]["Country"] = [key] * len(years)
        od[key][row[0]].extend(islice(row,1,None))
```

Output:

```
OrderedDict([('USA', defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'GDP': ['10', '11', '12', '12', '13'], 'Inf': ['100', '120', '130', '120', '110'], 'Years': ['1995', '1996', '1997', '1998', '1999'], 'Trade': ['200', '220', '210', '235', '250']})), ('GER', defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'GDP': ['8', '9', '9.5', '10', '10.5'], 'Inf': ['100', '105', '107', '109', '111'], 'Years': ['1995', '1996', '1997', '1998', '1999'], 'Trade': ['150', '156', '149', '165', '167']}))])
```

Someone more experienced in pandas will be able to get a nicer way to do this no doubt but this will at least create a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Country","Years","GDP","Inf","Trade"])

for k,v in od.items():
    df_temp = pd.DataFrame((v[k] for k in ["Country","Years","GDP","Inf","Trade"] ),["Country","Years","GDP","Inf","Trade"]).transpose()
    f = df.append(df_temp,ignore_index=True)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    Country Years   GDP  Inf Trade
0     USA  1995    10  100   200
1     USA  1996    11  120   220
2     USA  1997    12  130   210
3     USA  1998    12  120   235
4     USA  1999    13  110   250
5     GER  1995     8  100   150
6     GER  1996     9  105   156
7     GER  1997   9.5  107   149
8     GER  1998    10  109   165
9     GER  1999  10.5  111   167
```

If you file is larger you could also create the dataframe as you go and reset the OrderedDict each time to avoid storing all the data in the dict also, you just have to append the last group outside the main code, we can also use itertools.islice to get all the slices and use itertools.izip to zip if using python2:

```
import csv
from collections import OrderedDict,defaultdict
from itertools import islice,izip

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Country","Years","GDP","Inf","Trade"])
with open("out.csv") as f:
    od = OrderedDict()
    r = csv.reader(f, delimiter=" ")
    header = next(r)
    years = header[2:]
    zipped = izip(*r)
    countries = OrderedDict.fromkeys(next(zipped)).keys()
    it = iter(countries)
    for row in izip(*zipped):
        if row[0] == "GDP":
            if od: # make sure it is not the first line
                for k, v in od.items():
                    df_temp = pd.DataFrame((v[k] for k in ["Country","Years","GDP","Inf","Trade"] ), ["Country","Years","GDP","Inf","Trade"]).transpose()
                    df = df.append(df_temp, ignore_index=True)
                    od = OrderedDict()
            key = next(it)
            od.setdefault(key, defaultdict(list))
            od[key]["Years"] = years
            od[key]["Country"] = [key] * len(years)
        od[key][row[0]].extend(islice(row, 1, None))

for k,v in od.items():
        df_temp = pd.DataFrame((v[k] for k in ["Country","Years","GDP","Inf","Trade"] ), ["Country","Years","GDP","Inf","Trade"]).transpose()
        df = df.append(df_temp, ignore_index=True)


print(df)
```

Which should again give the same output:

```
  Country Years   GDP  Inf Trade
0     USA  1995    10  100   200
1     USA  1996    11  120   220
2     USA  1997    12  130   210
3     USA  1998    12  120   235
4     USA  1999    13  110   250
5     GER  1995     8  100   150
6     GER  1996     9  105   156
7     GER  1997   9.5  107   149
8     GER  1998    10  109   165
9     GER  1999  10.5  111   167
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have your data in a list of lists:

```
>>> for line in data:
...     print('\t'.join(line))
...
USA  GDP    10   11   12   12   13
USA  Inf    100  120  130  120  110
USA  Trade  200  220  210  235  250
GER  GDP    8    9    9.5  10   10.5
GER  Inf    100  105  107  109  111
GER  Trade  150  156  149  165  167
```

with following code:

```
from collections import defaultdict
data2 = defaultdict(dict)
for line in data:
    for i, year in ((2,1995),(3,1996),(4,1997),(5,1998),(6,1999)):
        data2[(line[0], year)][line[1]] = line[i]
data3 = [[i,j]+[data2[(i,j)][k] for k in ('GDP','Inf','Trade')] for i,j in data2]
for line in sorted(data3):
    print(line)
```

you get:

```
['GER', 1995, '8', '100', '150']
['GER', 1996, '9', '105', '156']
['GER', 1997, '9.5', '107', '149']
['GER', 1998, '10', '109', '165']
['GER', 1999, '10.5', '111', '167']
['USA', 1995, '10', '100', '200']
['USA', 1996, '11', '120', '220']
['USA', 1997, '12', '130', '210']
['USA', 1998, '12', '120', '235']
['USA', 1999, '13', '110', '250']
```

Answer (score 2):

This answer is going to be a lot like @AmiTavory's deleted answer (using `unstack` instead of `pivot_table`, but they're equivalent here) with one extra step at the end:

```
df2 = pd.melt(df, id_vars=["Countries", "variable"], var_name="Years")
df2 = df2.set_index(["Countries", "Years", "variable"]).unstack().reset_index()
df2.columns = [x[1] if x[1] else x[0] for x in df2.columns]
```

produces

```
In [149]: df2
Out[149]: 
  Countries Years   GDP  Inf  Trade
0       GER  1995   8.0  100    150
1       GER  1996   9.0  105    156
2       GER  1997   9.5  107    149
3       GER  1998  10.0  109    165
4       GER  1999  10.5  111    167
5       USA  1995  10.0  100    200
6       USA  1996  11.0  120    220
7       USA  1997  12.0  130    210
8       USA  1998  12.0  120    235
9       USA  1999  13.0  110    250
```

---

This works because first we create a melted version of the frame:

```
In [160]: df2 = pd.melt(df, id_vars=["Countries", "variable"], var_name="Years")

In [161]: df2
Out[161]: 
   Countries variable Years  value
0        USA      GDP  1995   10.0
1        USA      Inf  1995  100.0
2        USA    Trade  1995  200.0
3        GER      GDP  1995    8.0
4        GER      Inf  1995  100.0
5        GER    Trade  1995  150.0
6        USA      GDP  1996   11.0
[...]
```

and then we set the index and unstack:

```
In [166]: df2 = df2.set_index(["Countries", "Years", "variable"]).unstack().reset_index()

In [167]: df2
Out[167]: 
         Countries Years value           
variable                   GDP  Inf Trade
0              GER  1995   8.0  100   150
1              GER  1996   9.0  105   156
2              GER  1997   9.5  107   149
3              GER  1998  10.0  109   165
4              GER  1999  10.5  111   167
5              USA  1995  10.0  100   200
6              USA  1996  11.0  120   220
7              USA  1997  12.0  130   210
8              USA  1998  12.0  120   235
9              USA  1999  13.0  110   250
```

which is almost what we want, but the columns are too complicated.  We can fix it, though:

```
In [168]: df2.columns
Out[168]: 
MultiIndex(levels=[['value', 'Years', 'Countries'], ['GDP', 'Inf', 'Trade', '']],
           labels=[[2, 1, 0, 0, 0], [3, 3, 0, 1, 2]],
           names=[None, 'variable'])

In [169]: df2.columns = [x[1] if x[1] else x[0] for x in df2.columns]

In [170]: df2
Out[170]: 
  Countries Years   GDP  Inf  Trade
0       GER  1995   8.0  100    150
1       GER  1996   9.0  105    156
2       GER  1997   9.5  107    149
3       GER  1998  10.0  109    165
4       GER  1999  10.5  111    167
5       USA  1995  10.0  100    200
6       USA  1996  11.0  120    220
7       USA  1997  12.0  130    210
8       USA  1998  12.0  120    235
9       USA  1999  13.0  110    250
```

Answer (score 1):

I copy pasted your data into a spreadsheet. Maybe the renaming is not necessary, but I think the column name `variable` produced an error. Additionally, I did not check whether this is the least RAM consuming method.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_excel('df_countries.xls','Sheet1')
df.columns=['countries','var','1995','1996','1997','1998','1999']
df_new  = pd.melt(df,id_vars=['countries','var'])
df_new.columns = ['countries','var','year','data']
df_new.set_index(['countries','year','var']).unstack('var')
```

[image]